# Do we have to develop a special web UI after mobile app development completes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

We are excited to start developing mobile app using Flutter and backend applications that are running on Django with REST APIs. Our understanding is that once a mobile app is completely developed, we can simply launch the UI on a web browser as well with probably minor changes? Is this really true? if it is true, does our mobile app developer have to start coding the app to make it compatible for both mobile, web browser and desktop since from the beginning so that we don´t have to spend extra cycles to make the UI compatible with web browser and desktop? Or is Flutter supposed to be compatible by default for any UI clients ( Web browser, smart devices and desktop)? I would appreciate it if someone can confirm and point me to a relevant article?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

There ara small adjustments you need to make. For example some plugins are not supported for web of vice versa. So you need to avoid from using them.
Also while building UI, if your developer does not make it responsive, you would have a ugly mobile UI. So my advice is both web and mobile should go on hand to hand to avoid and end product mistakes.
Note that there are even small differences between Android and IOS